# Really Easy Question about CMS ! the directory setting

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I got my custom template on my 
**app/design/frontend/default/default/template/Company/contacts.phtml**

Then, I want to put it on my CMS. How Can i write on that cms part?
The information about BBB.phtml is in **/app/code/local/company/Contacts**

```
{{block type="?????????" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="?????????"}}
```

how can i set these blanks?

Comment: please provide your config.xml file

Answer (score 0):

You can all any phtml file in a cms page or static block using this code:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="Company/contacts.phtml"}}
```